# can't see all pages in dashboard (can only see 3) /wp-admin/edit.php > 500 error

Tags: post-editor

A client's website has 12 pages, but we can both only see 3 of them, even though we have administrator accounts, and creating a new administrator account does not solve the problem.

Screen Options will not open, and if I check the Chrome console, I see:

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 ():
>   /wp-admin/edit.php

I can see `/wp-admin/edit.php` exists.

I have removed `/wp-admin` and `/wp-includes` and uploaded fresh copies of these.

I have uploaded a fresh copy of the parent theme, and the child theme is untouched.

If I rename `plugins` to `plugins.temp` the issue remains.

Help appreciated.

**EDIT1**

If I turn debug on, and reload `/wp-admin/edit.php?post_type=page`, I see the following errors:

> Warning: Illegal string offset 'slideshow' in
>   /home/user/public_html/wp-content/themes/abundance/includes/admin/compat.php
>   on line 48
>
> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Cannot use string offset as an array in
>   /home/user/public_html/wp-content/themes/abundance/includes/admin/compat.php:48
>   Stack trace: #0
>   /home/user/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(298):
>   avia_backend_compatibility_custom_field_filter('', 127) #1
>   /home/user/public_html/wp-includes/plugin.php(203):
>   WP_Hook->apply_filters('', Array) #2
>   /home/user/public_html/wp-content/themes/abundance/framework/php/function-set-avia-frontend.php(262):
>   apply_filters('avia_post_meta_...', '', 127) #3
>   /home/user/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(300):
>   avia_post_meta(Object(WP_Post)) #4
>   /home/user/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(323):
>   WP_Hook->apply_filters('', Array) #5
>   /home/user/public_html/wp-includes/plugin.php(515):
>   WP_Hook->do_action(Array) #6
>   /home/user/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-query.php(4070):
>   do_action_ref_array('the_post', Array) #7
>   /home/user/public_html/wp-includes/query.php(938):
>   WP_Query->setup_postdata(Object(WP_Post)) #8 /home/mag in
>   /home/user/public_html/wp-content/themes/abundance/includes/admin/compat.php
>   on line 48

**EDIT2**

Here is line 44 to 61 of `/abundance/includes/admin/compat.php`

```
function avia_backend_compatibility_custom_field_filter($custom_fields, $post_id)
{
    if(empty($custom_fields))
    {
        $custom_fields['slideshow'][0]['slideshow_image'] = "";
    }

    if(isset($custom_fields['slideshow']) && is_array($custom_fields['slideshow']) && isset($custom_fields['slideshow'][0]['slideshow_image']))
    {
        $post_thumbnail_id = get_post_meta( $post_id, '_thumbnail_id', true );

        if($custom_fields['slideshow'][0]['slideshow_image'] == "" && $post_thumbnail_id)
        {
            $custom_fields['slideshow'][0]['slideshow_image'] = $post_thumbnail_id;
        }
    }
    return $custom_fields;
}
```

Comment: This has now been asked [in the comments on themeforest](https://themeforest.net/item/abundance-ecommerce-business-theme/759562/comments?page=25&filter=all#comment_17764006), from the outside it is difficult to help here, see [this answer explaining the error message](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20271518).

Answer (score 1):

1. Please open your wp-config.php file and change the parameter like this:

   ```
   define('WP_DEBUG', true);
   ```

Once this parameter is activated, you can see more details about the error.

2. Try to activate any default WordPress theme like TwentySeventeen and look if the error still exists.

Update:

```
function avia_backend_compatibility_custom_field_filter($custom_fields, $post_id)
{
    if(empty($custom_fields))
    {
        $custom_fields = array(
             'slideshow' => array(
                 array( 'slideshow_image' => '' )
             )
        );
    }

    if(isset($custom_fields['slideshow']) && is_array($custom_fields['slideshow']) && isset($custom_fields['slideshow'][0]['slideshow_image']))
    {
        $post_thumbnail_id = get_post_meta( $post_id, '_thumbnail_id', true );

        if($custom_fields['slideshow'][0]['slideshow_image'] == "" && $post_thumbnail_id)
        {
            $custom_fields['slideshow'][0]['slideshow_image'] = $post_thumbnail_id;
        }
    }
    return $custom_fields;
}
```

Comment: Ok, now you can see that the problem is here:  /home/user/public_html/wp-content/themes/abundance/includes/admin/compat.php on line 48, you can paste in your question that part of the code (lines 38-58 should be ok) and I will try to help

Comment: while might be helpful, this is a comment, not an answer.... you have enough rep to commetn ;)

Comment: I've updated the answer, please try to replace that code and let me know what happens.